# Add elements to an arraylist in Java with a 'for' loop where the element name has an increasing number

Tags: java, for-loop

I have an arraylist where I want to add elements via a *for* loop.

```
Answer answer1;
Answer answer2;
Answer answer3;

ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList(3);

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    answers.add( /* HOWTO: Add each of the answers? */ );
}
```

How would this go if I have, let's say, 50 *Answer* elements?

Comment: i think the importent question is: what's your input? do you want to add fields? or an array? or another list?

Comment: Thaks for input every one. I think I need to redefine the way I'm trying to do this... Best hint for me was what Chris wrote.. I'm going with that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do it the way you're trying to... But you can perhaps do something like this:

```
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
  Answer temp = new Answer();
  // Do whatever initialization you need here
  answers.add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That can't be done with a `for`-loop, unless you use the Reflection API. However, you can use [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) instead to accomplish the same:

```
List<Answer> answers = Arrays.asList(answer1, answer2, answer3);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm getting incompatible types: no instance(s) found of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: set your variable type to `List` instead of `ArrayList`. It's a good habit to use the lowest possible interface.

Answer (score 4):

I assume `Answer` as an Integer data type, so in this case you can easily use `Scanner` class for adding the multiple elements (say, 50).

```
private static final Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(50);

public static void main(String...S) {

  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    /* Using Scanner class object to take input. */
    arrayList.add(obj.nextInt());
  }

  /* You can also check the elements of your ArrayList. */
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    /* Using get function for fetching the value present at index 'i'. */
    System.out.print(arrayList.get(i) + " ");
  }

}
```

This is a simple and easy method for adding multiple values in an ArrayList using a *for* loop.

As in the above code, I presume the `Answer` as Integer. It could be `String`, `Double`, `Long`, etc. So, in that case, you can use `next()`, `nextDouble()`, and `nextLong()`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply need a list, you could use:

```
List<Answer> answers = Arrays.asList(answer1, answer2, answer3);
```

If you specifically require an `ArrayList`, you could use:

```
ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(answer1, answer2, answer3));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's always some reflection hacks that you can adapt. Here is some example, but using a collection would be the solution to your problem (the integers you stick on your variables name is a good hint telling us you should use a collection!).

```
public class TheClass {

    private int theField= 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TheClass c= new TheClass();

        System.out.println(c.getClass().getDeclaredField("theField").get(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a *for* loop for this. The solution is very obvious:

```
answers.add(answer1);
answers.add(answer2);
answers.add(answer3);
```

That's it. No *for* loop needed.

Comment: I guess there are probably more than 3, and the the total number can change

Comment: Yes, it's easy enough for 3 elements, but what if I have 100?

Comment: but: are the answers fields? - in his example they are. what's the input?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to put the answers into an array and iterate over it:

```
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>(3);

for (Answer answer : new Answer[] {answer1, answer2, answer3}) {
    list.add(answer);
}
```

But see [João's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268921/add-elements-to-an-arraylist-in-java-with-a-for-loop-where-the-element-name-ha/8268951#8268951) for a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268921/add-elements-to-an-arraylist-in-java-with-a-for-loop-where-the-element-name-ha/8268950#8268950) is good enough for this matter.

If you want to use a loop to access these three *Answers*, you first need to put there three into an array-like data structure ---- kind of like a principle. So a loop is used for operating on an array-like data structure, not just simply to simplify the typing task. And you cannot use a *for* loop by simply just giving increasing-number-names to the elements.

Comment: Re *"And you cannot use a* ***for*** *loop by simply just giving increasing-number-names to the elements."*: Why not? Couldn't [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) be used?

Answer (score 1):

Using the *Random* function to generate numbers and iterating them on `al` using a *for* loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

for (int i=0; i<=4; i++){

    Random rand = new Random();
    al.add(i, rand.nextInt(100));
    System.out.println(al);
}

System.out.println(al.size());
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, read the question again - he is looking for increasing number, not random

Comment: You can just remove random function and simply use increasing number instead off providing random numbers.