# Add multiple items to an already initialized arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

My `arraylist` might be populated differently based on a user setting, so I've initialized it with

```
ArrayList<Integer> arList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

How can I add hundreds of integers without doing it one by one with `arList.add(55);`?

Comment: I already answer this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368082/10304471

Comment: @Trishant Saxena: No, not for the general case. More like [rhino9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/add-multiple-items-to-an-already-initialized-arraylist-in-java/52811238#52811238). Though the question is underspecified.

Comment: Do you want to add ***the same number*** hundreds of times? Or are they arbitrary numbers?

Comment: This ***must*** have been a duplicate in 2013, nearly 5 years after the launch of Stack Overflow. What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

If you have another list that contains all the items you would like to add you can do `arList.addAll(otherList)`. Alternatively, if you will always add the same elements to the list you could create a new list that is initialized to contain all your values and use the `addAll()` method, with something like

```
Integer[] otherList = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
arList.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherList));
```

or, if you don't want to create that unnecessary array:

```
arList.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Otherwise you will have to have some sort of loop that adds the values to the list individually.

Comment: Really, I thought there was a better way? Oh well, looping works. Thx

Comment: Yeah, unless you want to create a new list that is initialized with all your values (see my edit above), those are your options.

Comment: The second one is definitely the most concise way of doing it

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 32):

What is the "source" of those integers?  If it is something that you need to hard code in your source code, you may do

```
arList.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
```

Comment: This is definitely the most concise way of doing it.

Answer (score 14):

[`Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) is a varargs method which allows us to add any number of items to a collection in a single statement:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

It can also be used to add array elements to a collection:

```
Integer[] arr = ...;
Collections.addAll(list, arr);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to avoid multiple code lines to save space, maybe this syntax could be useful:

```
        java.util.ArrayList lisFieldNames = new ArrayList() {
            {
                add("value1"); 
                add("value2");
            }
        };
```

Removing new lines, you can show it compressed as:

```
        java.util.ArrayList lisFieldNames = new ArrayList() {
            {
                add("value1"); add("value2"); (...);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Still requires multiple calls to `add()` and adds clutter even if it is compressed to one line

Comment: I would have the values in a String Ej. String theValues="1,20,2,1001"; (by hand or loaded from a File). Then pass it to Array: Integer[] theArray = theValues.split(",", -1);   Once you have the array, it's easy to pass it to ArrayList: ArrayList<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray));  . (Not tested)

Comment: Here's a more [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761018) on why this works.

Answer (score 2):

[Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-)+ now allows this:

```
List<Integer> arList = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

The list will be [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) though.

Comment: Finally, this is the one line method to add multiple elements to one list. No loops, no additional lists, one simple line of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to add a lot of integers it'd probably be easiest to use a *for* loop. For example, adding 28 days to a daysInFebruary array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> daysInFebruary = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
    daysInFebruary.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes, for some of the examples in answers here. But otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

In a [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) way;

```
val arList = ArrayList<String>()
arList.addAll(listOf(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score -6):

I believe [scaevity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/add-multiple-items-to-already-an-initialized-arraylist-in-java/15213992#15213992) is incorrect. The proper way to initialize with multiple values would be this...

```
int[] otherList = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

So the full answer with the proper initialization would look like this

```
int[] otherList = {1,2,3,4,5};
arList.addAll(Arrays.asList(otherList));
```

Comment: This does not compile because int is a primitive type and Arrays.asList() does not work correctly on arrays of primitive types. The chosen answer uses Integer, and that is the correct way to do it.