# How to add many values to an arraylist at once?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have the following code:

```
String a = " some texte";
String b = " text";
String c = "sf ";
String d = " kjel";
String e = "lkjl";

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// better way to do all these adds without having to type them all?
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
list.add(e);
```

How can I make this more efficient for both typing and computing?

Comment: I'd recommend you to look here, potential duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/add-multiple-items-to-already-initialized-arraylist-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing ArrayList with some predefined values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194921/initializing-arraylist-with-some-predefined-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java 8 :

```
List<String> yourList= Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d,e);
```

you can make it shorter by static import: `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`

in java 9 you can use list of:

```
List<String> yourList = List.of(a,b,c,d,e);
```

and in java 10 and later there is a keyword named `var`:

```
var yourList = List.of(a,b,c,d,e);
```

in this way yourList will be immutable so it can not be changed.

you can also use `Stream`:

```
List<String> yourList= Stream.of(a,b,c,d,e).collect(toList());
```

or

```
Stream<String>  yourList= Stream.of(a,b,c,d,e);
```

Answer (score 5):

On a single line, you can do:

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also Guava:

```
 ArrayList<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Comment: +1 for Guava, although the problem here is too trivial to add a third-party library.

Comment: I agree. It is just an alternative solution.