# append new items to an array contained in a hash map by key value

Tags: java, hashmap, append

I'm reading all the files of a directory and trying to save all the words, from all the files associated within that directory to a hash map, these words will be stored under a key which is the name of the directory.

for instance, a directory called `atheism` contains one file called `a0.txt` which contains the word `Gott`, another file in the same directory called `a1.txt` contains the word `ist`, and a third file called `a2.txt` contains the word `tot`. I want to save all these words under the hash map key `atheism`.

Later I want to generalize this to be able to accomidate big multi-line documents behind the key value of a particular directory, below I've posted the code which I'm working with right now to populate the hash map.

I had a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/add-multiple-items-to-already-initialized-arraylist-in-java) trying to adapt it but finally I didn't find it aplicable to my situation.

What I want to do is access the array associated with a specific key from within the hashmap, and just add the new words onto the end of it. How to do that?

I need these words because this is part of a program to implement the perceptron algorithm, I'm saving the words as part of the process of generating a bag-of-words model feature vector.

```
public static void iterateDirectory( File directory, 
                                     boolean globo_dict_fixed, 
                                     Map<String, ArrayList<String> > fileDict,
                                     Set<String> GLOBO_DICT) throws IOException 
{
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (file.isDirectory()) 
        {
            iterateDirectory(directory, globo_dict_fixed, fileDict, GLOBO_DICT );
        } 
        else 
        {   
            String line; 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file ));


            ArrayList<String> document_words_on_line = new ArrayList<String>();

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words

                if(globo_dict_fixed == false)
                {
                    Data_GloboPop.populate_globo_dict( words, GLOBO_DICT );
                }
                else
                {
                    String word;

                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
                    {
                        word = words[i];

                        document_words_on_line.add(word);
                    }

                }

            }
            String key_file_loke = file.getPath()
                                       .toString()
                                       .replaceAll("/[^/]*$", "")
                                       .replaceAll("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/practice_data/data/train/", "")
                                       .replaceAll("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/ISTD_50.570/assignments/practice_data/data/test/", "");
            //this should be here, meaning that the line is null and the file is over

            //put all documents from the same directory under the same key
            fileDict.put( key_file_loke , document_words_on_line );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a quick question, so you need to add all the text content files from a directory under a directory name? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Pasupathi I just wrote it up as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this model

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> directoryFiles = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> fileNameAndContents = new HashMap<>();
//Create all file contents map add it to main map
directoryFiles.put("directory", fileNameAndContents);


public static void main(String[] d) throws Exception {
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> directoryFiles = new HashMap<>();
    listfileContent("d:/f1",directoryFiles);
    System.out.println(directoryFiles.toString());
}

public static void listfileContent(String directoryName,Map<String,Map<String,String>> directoryFiles) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Map<String,String> fileNameAndContents = new HashMap<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            fileNameAndContents.put(file.getName(), "FileContent " );
            directoryFiles.put(directoryName, fileNameAndContents);

        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listfileContent(file.getAbsolutePath(),directoryFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will help you. "FileContent " place you can write a function to get the data from a file.

Comment: would you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Well you want to -- "access the array associated with a specific key from within the hashmap"

Sure, instead of initializing the ArrayList each time, you can always replace this line
`ArrayList<String> document_words_on_line = new ArrayList<String>();`
 with this line
`ArrayList<String> document_words_on_line = fileDict.get(key_file_loke);`
And compute the `key_file_loke` before the assignment of `document_words_on_line`.

[Update] :
If you get a null then initialize it, else use the same reference.
In short : 

`String key_file_loke = Insert your existing logic;
ArrayList<String> document_words_on_line = fileDict.get(key_file_loke);
if(document_words_on_line == null){
ArrayList<String> document_words_on_line = new ArrayList<String>();
}`

Comment: so where should i initialize that array list? i should make it a global variable or soemthing?

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work. I'm going to post what i've done in a new answer could you check it out? ok, i just placed it.

Comment: java doesn't like that. it says 'duplicate local variable'

Comment: Well, I was trying to give you an idea of what you could do. Not write the code for you.

Comment: my bad i'm not trying to be a dick, i've been coding this for many hours now and i think my brain is sort of friend, please forgive me

Comment: you mean "sort of fried" .. Take a break :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to replace this part of code

```
if (file.isDirectory()) 
{
    iterateDirectory(directory, globo_dict_fixed, fileDict, GLOBO_DICT );
}
```

with fhis

```
if (file.isDirectory()) 
{
    iterateDirectory(file, globo_dict_fixed, fileDict, GLOBO_DICT );
}
```

Next, you should put new key-value pair into hashmap as soon as you find a new directory, before you start looking for words in this directory. So you don't need to check and create new List and key-value pair for each file in the same directory (assuming you have a directory with lots of files).

For example

```
for (File file : directory.listFiles()) 
{
    if (file.isDirectory()) 
    {
        fileDict.put(getDirectoryName(file), new LinkedList<>());
        iterateDirectory(file, globo_dict_fixed, fileDict, GLOBO_DICT );
    } 
    else 
    {   
        final String directoryName = getDirectoryByFilePath(file); // you should extract this method from your code
        List<String> wordsList = fileDict.get(directoryName);
        if(wordsList == null) { // just in case
            wordsList = new LinkedList<>();
            fileDict.put(directoryName, wordsList);
        }

        String line; 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file ));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words
            if(globo_dict_fixed == false)
            {
                Data_GloboPop.populate_globo_dict( words, GLOBO_DICT );
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
                {
                        wordsList.add(words[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if it you do not care about accessing words by random index, I recommend to use LinkedList instead of ArrayList.

Comment: i'm feeling so confused, I've been programming for hours. can you show me what your talking about please?

Comment: so that is the full method?

Comment: Also, you might find some problems with files with same name in different directories.

Comment: it's saying getDirectoryName and getDirectoryByFilePath are undefined

Comment: Yes, I commented this in my answer: you should implement this methods. First one must extract directory name from a file which is directory (probably just file.getName(), but consider hierarchy). Second one shoul do the same, but for the file in this directory. So pogram puts all words from this file to the correct place in your hashmap.