# Looped elements ArrayList of ArrayLists elements being changed to last looped value

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I can not figure out why each element in the "ALofcompoundedPrimeAL" which is an ArrayList of ArrayList is ending up with each element being the same. So while the ArrayList "theNewPrimeFactorsAL" looks to be correct, each iteration of the for loop seems to change all elements of ALofcompoundedPrimeAL to be that of the latest iteration; that is ALofcompoundedPrimeAL is not indexing unique elements, instead each element is changed to the value of the last loop iteration.  As an extra, would I be using the right tools to store sets of sets? It is important that I can count the number of prime factors from iteration to iteration so can't just make a new set with possible new prime divisors.

I found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268921/java-add-elements-to-arraylist-with-for-loop-where-element-name-has-increasing) which apparently works but can not seem to get loop to not update each element in ALofcompoundedPrimeAL to be the value of the last iteration.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> CompoundDivisors(
        ArrayList<Set<Integer>> SetofallPrimeFactorsAL) {

    Set<Integer> PrimeFactorsSET;
    ArrayList<Integer> theNewPrimeFactorsAL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ALofcompoundedPrimeAL = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    ArrayList<Integer> thePrimeFactorsAL;
    for (int k = 0; k < SetofallPrimeFactorsAL.size(); k++) {
        PrimeFactorsSET = SetofallPrimeFactorsAL.get(k);
        // PrimeFactorsAL takes the set of Prime Factors (in
        // PrimeFactorsSET) and outputs an arraylist of them.
        thePrimeFactorsAL = new ArrayList<Integer>(PrimeFactorsSET);
        // theNewPrimeFactorsAL.addAll just adds all of the new elements to
        // the theNewPrimeFactorsAL ArrayList.
        theNewPrimeFactorsAL.addAll(thePrimeFactorsAL);
        // ALofcompoundedPrimeAL is supposed to add theNewPrimeFactorsAL to
        // each index.
        ALofcompoundedPrimeAL.add(theNewPrimeFactorsAL);
    }
    return (ALofcompoundedPrimeAL);
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Looks like Java.  I added the "java" tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just copy references around.  For example, after you added `theNewPrimeFactorsAL` to `ALofcompoundedPrimeAL`, you proceed to `addAll` to the same `theNewPrimeFactorsAL` in the next loop.  At the end, `ALofcompoundedPrimeAL` contains *n* references to the same `theNewPrimeFactorsAL`, which holds all elements added to it in any iteration of the loop.

You need to create new lists to have new lists.