# Java adding elements to arraylist and good practices

Tags: java, arraylist, coding-style

I am dealing with adding objects to lists and have faced some problems while assigning new values to `temporary` object. I've come up with myself and found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268921/java-add-elements-to-arraylist-with-for-loop-where-element-name-has-increasing) an answer, but I can't add comments and my question is: is it a good practice to create a new instance of a class each time I want to add an element in a loop? What about the memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add objects to your list, are these new objects, or are you pulling existing ones from some other list or data structure? If it's the former (they are new), then you must construct them as you add them (new instances).

Comment: I iterate over some data string to extract data and assing it to an object and then to a list. It will look similarily to this:
`for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
     temporary = new MyObject();
     temporary = extractData();
     myList.add(temporary.temporaryField)
     }`