# ArrayList inserting multiple elements

Tags: java, arraylist, vaadin

I am new in Vaadin and Java and I am dealing the problem below:

In the following code, I want to add multiple elements in the **ArrayList "newlist"**. As you can see, the elements named "ps" have 5 sub-elements.

The problem is that the current(in-the-loop) element added in the ArrayList is replacing all the previous ones in each index and as a result in the end it returns only the last "ps" element, as many times as the loop is occured.

[image]

**How can I store each "ps" element in the different indexes?**

**And the code:**

```
Collection<?> itemIds =  table.getItemIds();
Item item = null;
PS_SECTION ps = new PS_SECTION();
List<PS_SECTION> newlist = new ArrayList<PS_SECTION>();
int i = 0;

             for(Object itemId : itemIds){   

                    item = table.getItem(itemId);// row
                    Long s1 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ID").getValue();
                    String s2 = item.getItemProperty("ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ").getValue().toString();
                    Long s3 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ΔΙΑΤΑΞΗ").getValue();
                    Long s4 = 0L;
                    Long s5 = 0L;

                    ps.setPS_SECTION(s1);
                    ps.setNAME(s2);
                    ps.setVORDER(s3);
                    ps.setISACTIVE(s4);
                    ps.setISGLOBAL(s5);

                    newlist.add(ps);
                    i++                     
                 }
```

Comment: put `PS_SECTION ps = new PS_SECTION();` inside your for loop. Also...you shouldn't give classes names completly in Uppercase. "PsSection" would be in line with java naming conventions.

Comment: To explain what _911DidBush_ said, you need to create a new instance of `PS_SECTION` in your loop, here you are updating the same instance `ps` and adding it again and again

Comment: thanks! that helped!

Comment: I would add that your debugger shows the problem, the `PS_SECTION` all have the same `id`

Comment: Here is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268921/java-add-elements-to-arraylist-with-for-loop-where-element-name-has-increasing) to explain this.

Comment: @AxelH Problem solved! thanks

Comment: Your code has lots of "code smells". The very least to say, as mentioned by others is to rename your variables. Avoid names like "s1", "s2" and "ps" that have no meaning, use java standards (camel case). Clean code = less bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Collection<?> itemIds =  table.getItemIds();
Item item = null;
PS_SECTION ps = null; // Declare first ps to null, because you will instantiate it later
List<PS_SECTION> newlist = new ArrayList<PS_SECTION>();
int i = 0;

             for(Object itemId : itemIds){   

                    item = table.getItem(itemId);// row
                    Long s1 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ID").getValue();
                    String s2 = item.getItemProperty("ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ").getValue().toString();
                    Long s3 = (Long) item.getItemProperty("ΔΙΑΤΑΞΗ").getValue();
                    Long s4 = 0L;
                    Long s5 = 0L;

                    ps = new PS_SECTION() // put it here your instantiation
                    ps.setPS_SECTION(s1);
                    ps.setNAME(s2);
                    ps.setVORDER(s3);
                    ps.setISACTIVE(s4);
                    ps.setISGLOBAL(s5);

                    newlist.add(ps);
                    i++                     
                 }
```

Try to put your instantiation within the `loop` before you set the values. like the code above.

The Reason why you Instantiate `PS_SECTION` within the loop is to create a new `instance` of that `object` `PS_SECTION`. If you instantiate it outside the `loop`, you're just creating 1 object to be used in your `loop`, That's why all you've add in your `ArrayList` is all the same `objects`.

Comment: Try to explain why next time ... since this is explained in the comment!

Comment: Ok sir @AxelH, I will edit and explain. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @natso I edited it, and explain why you need to instantiate it within the for loop. credits to sir AxelH.